# princexml not working with python?

Tags: python, princexml

i'm using windows and want to subprocess princexml with python.

The docu says (http://www.princexml.com/doc/8.1/python/):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["prince","foo.xml","bar.pdf"]);
```

I replaced "prince" with the path to my binary exe...and i have an foo.xml in the same directory. The window with the generator gives a little blink and that was it...no pdf was generated.

Even when i just use prince on the cmd with "prince foo.xml foo.pdf" nothing happens...
Any help with that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Commercial software? Call your vendor.

Comment: oh this was a permission issue....

Comment: If you solved it, you can post your solution as an answer to a question and then accept it.  That way if someone else runs across the same problem, they can figure it out more easily. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself...it was the permission setting in windows...just install the engine to c:\users\somwhere and that it should be okay!